# Cocos2d Accessing CGRect properties of objects in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, object, properties, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray

I have a bunch of buildings declared in their own classes.. I add instances of these buildings to my game layer and also to NSMutableArray allBuildings.. All these buildings have a bunch of CGRect synthesised and declared in the class files..
My question is how to use access the CGRects of all the buildings in the allBuildings array, to use for collision without accessing each individual buildings in the array.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collection operator `@unionOfObjects` to get an array of all the rects. They will be stored in `NSValue` objects. For example I suppose that your property is called `rect`:

```
NSArray* rects= [allBuildings valueForKeyPath: @"@unionOfObjects.rect"];
```

Then you iterate through the array this way:

```
for(NSValue* value in rects) {
    CGRect rect= value.CGRectValue;
    <...>
}
```

Comment: ok i guess i understood the concept.. 
This is what i did 
`NSArray * verticalArray = [allBuildings valueForKey:@"@unionOfObjects.vertical1"];`
where verticals are the rects.. but when i try to use them for collision
`for (CGRect * vert1 in verticalArray)
`
it gives me an error saying CGRect is not a valid object.

Comment: I added the explanation of how iterating through the array of rects.

Comment: app crashes with this error in log `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key` although i am sure i am using the correct property and all the buildings have this properties.. i guess i will have to check collision for each one individually.. thanks anyways for your help

Comment: Could I see how you populate the array?